# Compare sociodemographic characteristics at multiple data collection points in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset where data for each ID is collected multiple times (maximum of 4 times). It looks something like this but I'm working with 200+ variables:

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
age_group<-c(17-24 years,NA,NA,NA,25-55,NA,NA,17-24 years,NA,NA,17-24 years,NA,NA,NA)
gender<-c(male,NA,NA,NA,male,NA,NA,female,NA,NA,female,NA,NA,NA)
marital_status<-c(partnered,NA,NA,NA,single,NA,NA,single,NA,NA,partnered,NA,NA,NA)
education<-c(high school,NA,NA,NA,university,NA,NA,university,NA,NA,university,NA,NA,NA)
collection_point<-c(0,1,2,3,0,1,3,0,1,2,0,1,2,3)
df<-data.frame(id,age_group,gender,marital_status,education,collection_point)
```

The `collection_point` variable represents when data was collected so 0 is baseline, 1 is immediate, 2 is 3 months follow up, and 3 is 6 months follow up. I used the `subset()` function to remove the baseline data to create a sociodemographics table using the `CreateTableOne()` function from the tableone package. The table looks something like this:

```
                                         Overall     
      n                                           400         
      age_group (%)                                           
       17-24 years                              300 ( 75.0) 
       25-55 years                              100 ( 25.9) 
      gender (%)                                     
       Male                                     200 ( 50.0) 
       Female                                   200 ( 50.0) 
      marital_status (%)                    
       Partnered                                200 ( 50.0) 
       Single                                   200 ( 50.0) 
      education (%)                                  
       high school                              100 ( 25.0) 
       University                               300 ( 75.0)
```

But I'd like to compare these characteristics according to the `collection_point` variable to make my desired output look something like this:

```
      collection_point                             0                 1                 2                 3   
      n                                           400               300               200               200
      age_group (%)                                           
       17-24 years                              300 ( 75.0)        200 ( 66.7)        100 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0)
       25-55 years                              100 ( 25.9)        100 ( 33.3)        100 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0)
      gender (%)                                     
       Male                                     200 ( 50.0)        150 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0) 
       Female                                   200 ( 50.0)        150 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0)
      marital_status (%)                    
       Partnered                                200 ( 50.0)        150 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0) 
       Single                                   200 ( 50.0)        150 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0) 
      education (%)                                  
       high school                              100 ( 25.0)        100 ( 33.3)        100 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0) 
       University                               300 ( 75.0)        200 ( 66.7)        100 ( 50.0)        100 ( 50.0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm still new to R and this platform and am trying to get used to it. Apologies in advance because I know how complicated this looks :(

EDIT: It worked, thank you! Just needed to add the `strata()` function and then used `CreateTableOne()` again. I created listVar1 and catVar2 variables.

```
listVar1<-c("age_group", "gender", "marital_status", "education") 
catVar2<-c("collection_point", "age_group", "gender", "marital_status", "education").
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the line of code with which you use TableOneCreate(). You would need to use starta = collection_point.

Comment: @jamoreiras That worked! I used: Table_2<- CreateTableOne(vars = listVar1, data = df, factorVars = catVar2, strata = c("collection_point")). Thank you!!

Comment: Excellent! Can you please add to the post the content of listVar1 and of catVar2?

Comment: @jamoreiras Yes! I'm having a lot of difficultly exporting the table if I stratify though. I used the write.table () function to save as .txt but I keep getting an error message even though it worked fine for the first table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the argument strata.

```
>Table_2 <-  CreateTableOne(vars = listVar1, data = df, 
                            factorVars = catVar2, 
                            strata = c("collection_point"))

>print(Table_2)
                    Stratified by collection_point
                     level       0         1        2        3        p    test
  n                              4         4        3        3
  age_group (%)      17-24 years 3 (75.0)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)   NaN
                     25-55       1 (25.0)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)
  education (%)      high school 1 (25.0)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)   NaN
                     university  3 (75.0)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)
  gender (%)         female      2 (50.0)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)   NaN
                     male        2 (50.0)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)
  marital_status (%) partnered   2 (50.0)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)   NaN
                     single      2 (50.0)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)  0 (NaN)
```